# Confused about .vue extensions - "Unknown custom element: <topmenu>"

Tags: templates, vue.js, electron, vue-component, vue-router

I try to get working the electron-vue boilerplate. After setting up the project everything works, but as I create a new .vue file (TopMenu.vue) I get:

```
vue.common.js?4eb4:2569 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <topmenu> -
did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make 
sure to provide the "name" option. (found in component <landing-page>)
```

I use the exact syntax as the original .vue files which came with the boilerplate:

LandingPageVue.vue:

```
<style scoped>
  img {
    margin-top: -25px;
    width: 450px;
  }
</style>

<template>
  <div>
    <!-- <img src="./LandingPageView/assets/logo.png" alt="electron-vue"> -->
    <h1>Welcome.</h1>
    <topmenu></topmenu>
    <current-page></current-page>
    <versions></versions>
    <links></links>

    <div class="container">

    </div>
</template>


<script>
  import TopMenu from './LandingPageView/TopMenu'
  import CurrentPage from './LandingPageView/CurrentPage'
  import Links from './LandingPageView/Links'
  import Versions from './LandingPageView/Versions'

  export default {
    components: {
      TopMenu,
      CurrentPage,
      Links,
      Versions
    },
    name: 'landing-page'
  }
</script>
```

TopMenu.vue (my file):

```
<template>
  <p>
    TOPMENU
  </p>
</template>
```

**By the way, how the hack does `<current-page></current-page>` work (notice the "-" dash) if bellow it is declared without?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you're not exporting anything in your vue file.

Try this in your TopMenu.vue file:

```
<template>
  <p>
    TOPMENU
  </p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    }
</script>
```

Also change the html `<topmenu></topmenu>` to `<top-menu></top-menu>`

For your second question, HTML is case insensitive so your title case components wouldn't match with html tags. So Vue translates your title case components to a 'dash-case'. 
From the documentation itself there's the explanation why:

> Note that Vue does not enforce the W3C rules for custom tag names (all-lowercase, must contain a hyphen) though following this convention is considered good practice.

You can read more from the the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html)

Comment: added, restarted, error still persists. I have checked CurrentPage.vue, it does not contain the mentioned script and that works.

Comment: try change your html `<topmenu></topmenu>` to `<top-menu></top-menu>`

Comment: Jeezz, it works! I was looking for hours in the docs...:(( But where is this mentioned (these conventions)?

Comment: follow the link in my edited answer. I'll also edited again with the correct answer. Glad i could help!

Comment: I have just now seen the changes, thanks! You are my saviour! :)